# Powershell to remove specific lists of groups from a user in a different domain

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am a beginner in PowerShell, so I have been tinkering around it to learn more about its uses. Currently I have a task that requires me to remove a list of chosen groups from a user.

The user is in a different domain, hence I have used LDAP.
I am able to find that user and bind it to an object using the command below:

```
[ADSI]$user = "LDAP://CN=xxx,OU=xxx,DC=xxx"*
```

so I am able to display whatever information required from `$user` e.g. `$user.sAMAccountName`, `$user.DisplayName` it works. Except for the users groups...

I try the command to remove the groups listed in the user based on sAMAccountName; as all the users in that domain is identified easier by sAMAccountName, it doesnt work.

this command was used just to see if I can remove one group first; if $user can be found and read by the command; it doesnt work

```
remove-adgroupmember "GroupName" $user.sAMAccountName
```

or when I tried to display the groups instead to see if $user can be read, it also doesnt work,

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership [ADSI]$user = "LDAP://CN=xxx,OU=xxx,DC=xxx" |
    select name
```

I have tried to search regarding this issue, but almost all the tips does not involve different domains or used ldap for other domains, it uses the primary domain instead, and I am not sure on how to edit that part.

If anyone can advice me I would be very grateful, thank you =)

Comment: Is there a trust between the domains?

Comment: yes there is if not mistaken

Comment: Are they in the same forest?  You should use the RSAT ActiveDirectory powershell module to interact with the domains (as it looks like you already are with that `Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` command in there)